# Need to know the difference between spring-boot-starter-parent and spring-boot-parent

Tags: spring-boot

Can someone explain me the difference between `spring-boot-parent` and `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Examples where they have written separate modules for `spring-boot-starter-parent` and `spring-boot-parent`:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/

What's the difference between these two dependencies?

In most of the projects we generally use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent but not `spring-boot-parent` when both of them shares the same parent `spring-boot-dependencies`.

Answer (score 9):

As described at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent

**Spring-boot-starter-parent**

> The spring-boot-starter-parent project is a special starter project –
> that provides default configurations for our application and a
> complete dependency tree to quickly build our Spring Boot project.
>
> It also provides default configuration for Maven plugins such as
> maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-jar-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin,
> maven-war-plugin.
>
> Beyond that, it also inherits dependency management from
> spring-boot-dependencies which is the parent to the
> spring-boot-starter-parent.

**spring-boot-parent**

> Sometimes we have a custom Maven parent. Or, we may prefer to declare
> all our Maven configurations manually.
>
> In that case, we may opt to not use the spring-boot-starter-parent
> project. But, we can still benefit from its dependency tree by adding
> a dependency spring-boot-dependencies in our project in import scope.

Comment: I notice spring-boot-parent has very few google-hits but it is on maven central. spring-boot-parent already includes dependency spring-boot-dependencies but that baeldung article linked above suggests also adding that dependency. It is talking about how to pull in spring-boot without using spring-boot-starter-parent. In their example they present some random, pre-existing "custom mvn parent" we don't want to change. They then call it "spring-boot-parent" then in the next sentence say they named it "parent-modules" which doesn't match. I believe "spring-boot-parent" itself was not intended.

Answer (score 2):

**Spring Boot Starter Parent** helps us with managing dependency versions, the java version used by project and the default configuration for plug-ins, as we don't have to specify a lot of things manually.

It helps us with the following :

- Configuration
- Dependency management
- Default plugin configuration (default configurations for `maven-failsafe-plugin`, `maven-jar-plugin` and `maven-surefire-plugin` etc)

According to spring-boot [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html) :

> Starters are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can
>   include in your application. You get a one-stop shop for all the
>   Spring and related technologies that you need without having to hunt
>   through sample code and copy-paste loads of dependency descriptors

The **spring-boot-starter** is the Core starter and provides functionalities including auto-configuration support, logging and YAML.It defines  `spring-boot-dependencies` as the parent pom .

In the github url that you provided , they have kept a separate module to specify the parent `spring-boot-dependencies` in the pom.It might be because they needed to use the `spring-boot-dependencies` , dependency tree alone without the auto-configuration and plugin configuration , and publish it as separate jar for some use-case.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
        <relativePath>../spring-boot-dependencies</relativePath>
     </parent>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant the difference between **spring-boot-starter-parent** and **spring-boot-starter**.

- **spring-boot-starter-parent** - has spring-boot-dependencies as the parent and hence provides various spring-boot dependencies and helps in dependency management. In addition to this spring-boot-starter-parent on it's own helps in plugin management as well.
  So if you use only spring-boot-dependencies you can benefit from the dependency management provided by it but instead if you use the spring-boot-starter-parent, you get dependency management + plugin management.
- **spring-boot-starter** - It is a dependency provided by spring-boot-dependencies which provides dependencies for autoconfigure, logging and also spring-core. In order to pull any dependency from the starter or from spring-boot-dependencies, you need to explicitly add it as a dependency in your main pom.